Specify that a pointer variable can not be null
I am aware that ISO C has no facility for this (yet), and that GNU C has __attribute__((nonnull)) for function parameters, and __attribute__((returns_nonnull)) for return values. But is there any extension for local variables, in either GCC or Clang?

C23 has (will have) 7 standard attributes — deprecated, fallthrough, maybe_unused, nodiscard, noreturn, unsequenced and reproducible.  These do not include any 'non-null' attributes.  It does allow for implementation-specific 'attribute prefixes' which could use a notation such as [[gcc::nonnull]].  If a compiler does not recognize an attribute, it must ignore it.  See §6.7.12 Attributes in draft versions of the C23 standard.  Note: the link is to a draft from September 2022.   Newer drafts are for C26 or are locked.

Yes, clang has _Nonnull to give the compiler a hint that you will not set it to NULL:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    void* _Nonnull x = NULL;
}

It's purely there to provide optimization hints and doesn't prevent you from actually setting it to NULL.

The _Nonnull nullability qualifier indicates that null is not a meaningful value for a value of the _Nonnull pointer type.



I am aware that ISO C has no facility for this

It has, for function parameters, since 25 years back:
void func (int ptr[static 1])

For details see What does the static keyword do in C?

You're right, but I was specifically wondering about local variables. The static keyword can not be used for a void *, a return value, or a local variable.

@Harith Well, you can do various ugly tricks like #define func(x) actual_func(x, &(int){0}) ... int* actual_func (int some_param, int not_null[static 1]) { int* ret_val = not_null; int* some_local = not_null; ... return ret_val; } Super ugly but should at least allow the compiler to perform optimizations assuming neither pointer is initialized as a null pointer. If you assign values to them from external functions etc then that is no longer true though.
